# JavaScript: How to map object with nested arrays to table for React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am pulling data from Firebase and I am trying to display it in a table with React.

Here is what my data looks like when I log the data array to the console:

```
Sampling0: {Time: "1575031318", Values: Array(6)}
Sampling1: {Time: "1575031965", Values: Array(6)}
Sampling2: {Time: "1575032607", Values: Array(6)}
Sampling3: {Time: "1575033253", Values: Array(6)}
Sampling4: {Time: "1575033926", Values: Array(6)}
Sampling5: {Time: "1575034577", Values: Array(6)}
```

Here is what the expanded data looks like for sampling1:

```
Sampling1:
Time: "1575031965"
Values: Array(6)
Spot0: 31
Spot1: 32
Spot2: 7
Spot3: 32
Spot4: 11
Spot5: 18
```

I am trying to map this data into a table with three columns for example:

Spot #  | Value | Sampling Period

Spot 0  | 31    | Sampling Period 1

Spot 1  | 32    | Sampling period 1  <-- Then move to sampling period 2

Spot 0  | 42    | Sampling Period 2

Spot 1  | 41    | Sampling period 2

Here's my code so far:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.renderCharts();
};

renderCharts() {
  const wordRef = firebase.database().ref('myTable');
  wordRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    let words = snapshot.val().myData;
    let newState = [];
    let myState = [];
    for (let word in words) {
      newState.push({
        Time: word,
        Values: words[word],
      })
}

 render() {
    return (
      <div className="animated fadeIn">
                 <Table responsive>
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Spot #</th>
                          <th>Values</th>
                          <th>Sampling period</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                          {this.state.words.map((d, index) => {
                              return [
                                  <tr key={d.index}>
                                    <td>?</td>
                                    <td>{d.Values[index]}</td> //This grabs the value in the proper index but for different sampling periods
                                    <td>{index}</td> //This properly displays sampling period #'s
                                  </tr>
                              ];
                            })}

                        </tbody>
                      </Table>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then one approach would be to preprocess the data returned from firebase [using reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) as shown below:

```js
const data = {
    Sampling1: {Time: "1575031965", Values: [
        { Spot0: 31 },
        { Spot1: 32 },
        { Spot2: 7 },
        { Spot3: 32 },
        { Spot4: 11 },
        { Spot5: 18 }
    ]},
    Sampling2: {Time: "1575032607", Values: [
        { Spot0: 42 },
        { Spot1: 41 },
    ]},
    Sampling3: {Time: "1575033253", Values: [
        { Spot0: 1 },
        { Spot1: 2 },
        { Spot2: 3 }
    ]}
  };

const tableData = Object.entries(data).reduce((arr, samplingEntry) => {

  // Extract key and value of current sampling entry
  const [samplingKey, samplingObject] = samplingEntry;
  
  const smaplingPeroidLabel = samplingKey.replace('Sampling', 'Sampling period ');
  
  // Iterate first two spot items of Values array for sampling object
  for(let i = 0; i < Math.min(2, samplingObject.Values.length); i++) {
  
    // Extract the first entry of this spot object
    const [spotEntry] = Object.entries(samplingObject.Values[i]);
    
    // Extract key and value of this spot entry
    const [spotKey, spotValue] = spotEntry;
    
    // Add spot key, spot value and sampling key as new row of arr
    arr.push([ spotKey, spotValue, smaplingPeroidLabel ]);
  }

  return arr;

}, []);

console.log(tableData);
```

The script above basically transforms your server response to an "array of arrays", where each sub array corresponds to a row of data in the table that you are rendering.

During your components `render()` phase, this data would first be mapped to `<tr>` elements and, where a secondary mapping would render the contents of that row element into `<td>` elements, eg:

```
// Existing JSX
<tbody>
{ tableData.map(row => <tr>{ row.map(cell => <td>{ cell }</td> }</tr>) }
</tbody>
// Existing JSX
```

Hope that helps!